# Error when using Tags during certificate import through Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure-keyvault

Issue description: (Please see below screen dump for reference)
Failure using Tag with Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate cmdlet.
The certificate would be imported into key vault okay even though I got the error message (as shown below).
However, I am not able to retrieve the certificate using Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate cmdlet, even though I could use Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret cmdlet (Tags displayed correctly).
Additional info
•   If I remove Tags from Azure portal or re-import the certificate without -Tag, I will still get the same error (Unable to cast object).
•   If I delete the cert and re-import the certificate without Tags, everything is working great.

Assistance needed:
I am using 5.1.2 Azure PowerShell. Please advise what am I missing. Thanks.

```
PS C:\Users\tonychou> $certificateTag = @{
    type = "certificate";
    subjectname = "rsppe-microsoft-com";
    alternatename = "dss";
    environment = "Test"
    };

PS C:\Users\tonychou> $certificatePasswordSecuredString = ConvertTo-SecureString $certificatePassword -AsPlainText -Force;
Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $kvName -CertificateName $certInCertName -FilePath $certificatePfxFile -Password $certificatePasswordSecuredString -Tag $certificateTag;

Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Hashtable'.
At line:2 char:1
+ Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $kvName -CertificateName $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate], InvalidCastException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.ImportAzureKeyVaultCertificate

PS C:\Users\tonychou> $certInCertificate = Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $kvName -Name $certInCertName;
Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Hashtable'.
At line:1 char:22
+ ... rtificate = Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $kvName -Name $ce ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate], InvalidCastException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.GetAzureKeyVaultCertificate

PS C:\Users\tonychou> $certInSecret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $kvName -Name $certInCertName;


PS C:\Users\tonychou> $certInCertificate 

PS C:\Users\tonychou> $certInSecret


SecretValue     : System.Security.SecureString
SecretValueText : MIIXegIBAzCCFzoGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCFysEghcnMIIXIzCCBgQGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCBfUEggXxMIIF7TCCBekGCyqGSIb3DQEMCgECoIIE9jCCBPIwHAYKKoZIhvcNAQwBAzAOBAgn0z9KUgiVSwICB9AEggTQ+38U79mo15qmAm7r0IgpGlveZFMHwqYt/LmEZOUyTKXv6GWHxkSoy/+dsa2XkVFruWas5WgqksMuwxY
                  43kum42JCzSHIkEzAbiN3zZNZWM7JDLaXBooR2bpOR49fdGdy44RmQjFGkU7w2cYLMjB+WSBQ9tt2xw4W1fJnv4d3vO44BQ/c2n1aHBZjmobdSrIDtpK8h+aiZyUrNix6wlifthI884h09rlF6ipBDicbgLn4NbpYPzfZlpa304fU9c7h0j/IDpdOi2zZOVT2Q3oc9ouMuSaKBC9CKE3Q99UBwyX/tZjM/A/uuW5nh3KQZ8
                  IJciW7/odBt3b9venZOHHbAZDns5iIzwop3hzSEDbQTqQ3hffdFEyUexHsq5AP2syveZYWlIrDpe9YJVB 

PS C:\Users\tonychou> Get-Module -ListAvailable | ?{$_.Name -eq "Azure"}


    Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                                                                                                       
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                                                                                                                       
Script     5.1.2      Azure                               {Get-AzureAutomationCertificate, Get-AzureAutomationConnection, New-AzureAutomationConnection, Remove-AzureAutomationConnection...}
```

Comment: Same error even if I imported the certificate without tags, then manually added tags. When retrieving the certificate with Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate cmdlet, I still got the below error:Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Hashtable'".

Comment: One person running Azure PowerShell 5.1.1 did not have this issue.

Comment: Confirmed working after installing PowerShell 6.1.0 and Az module. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

We suggest moving to Powershell version 6.0.0 and above

Comment: Are there any details about the error or a workaround? That would be useful for cases where you use this cmdlet not so often to avoid having to install version 6.